# How to dynamically load a child component view into parent component view in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

is there any way to load a component into another component.

Something like this.

ParentComponent - ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements {

  childComponentsSelector:string = "<app-child-component></app-child-component>"

}
```

ParentComponent - html

```
<div>
  <div [innerHTML]="childComponentsSelector"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using innerHtml property but it didnt work but I want to achieve something similar.

Comment: What you want to do is a really basic Angular feature, so take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Here you go : [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: @heaxyh yes the docs really helped, I got exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As others said the basic answer looks like dynamic components, however, in most cases using dynamic components decreases the readability of your code dramatically. As an alternative you can use *ngIf directive to achieve similar thing. You should be able to destroy and create a child component through using *ngIf directive.

Comment: my first choice was to use ngIf but it was making my code bulky as there are quite a lot of components, and also it reduced the flexibility of my code to load the components sequentially if any new component is added

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the CdkPortal from @angular/cdk package:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal